# Performance implication: Google Analytics Vs. Adobe Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, adobe-analytics

We use Google Analytics in our application, but now we need to change this and use Adobe Analytics instead.

While  doing the comparative study of both the tools, I am now aware of the pros and cons and featured offered by the tools,

But I didn't found any information about the performance implications on the application if we go forward with Adobe Analytics.

For this we have created two sample poc websites and included scripts for both of the tools in these applications respectively.

For GA we have inserted the script snipped in `<head>` tag and 
For AA we have reference the script source as provide by the client in `<head>` tag, and the following line at the bottom of the page before closing of `<body>` tag. `<script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>`

Following are the response time stats -

> 0.030 sec (GA) Vs 0.618 sec (AA)

Though the GA look much more fast than AA, but is it alarmingly low? Is it the correct way of using AA?

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the info you provided, your test isn't accurate.

`<script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>`

This tells me that you implemented Adobe Dynamic Tag Manager (DTM), which is not the core AA script. DTM is a tag manager and within the tag manager you can have any number of things in there that will increase page load time, including the tag manager library itself, and (presumably) AA.

If you want a better apples-to-apples comparison, either implement AA by itself (not through DTM) or perhaps instead implement GA through Google Tag Manager (GTM). Or perhaps even better, instead implement GA through DTM and disable AA and then swap to disabling GA to compare both within the context of DTM.

Comment: +1 for your response Crayon. I am very new to this, and it definitely provides a heads up. And require more research on it. Its not at straight forward, as I've anticipated it. DTM was alien jargon for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is also important to note that the s_code.js or DTM is a synchronous load whereas GA is asynch. This difference alone will have an impact on the overall load times.

As Crayon suggests, a better load comparison would be to deploy both using the native tools in DTM.

Hope this helps.